# How to fix django app error in edx-platform

Tags: django, openedx

I want to add a new app in the https://github.com/edx/edx-platform.
I am following this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ document

/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/myapp/url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   url('', views.hello, name = 'hello'),
]
```

/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/envs/common.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Standard ones that are always installed...
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djcelery',
    'myapp',
     .............
```

/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', branding_views.index, name='root'),   # Main marketing page, or redirect to courseware

    url(r'', include('student.urls')),
    # TODO: Move lms specific student views out of common code
    url(r'^dashboard/?$', student_views.student_dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^change_enrollment$', student_views.change_enrollment, name='change_enrollment'),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
```

My Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 123, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line([sys.argv[0]] + django_args)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import include, url, path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Where I am going wrong. please let me know.

Comment: you are using an older version of Django! please downgrade your Django app to `1.11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import include, url, path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

The above error is saying that you can't import `path` from `django.conf.urls`. It seems you are using older version of django. so, try the following command to install old version.

```
$ pip install Django==1.11
```

and go to file `/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/urls.py` and remove `path` from import. Then it looks like below.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
```

Comment: Thankyou Anjaneyulu, You are right, It is successfully compiled,  but when I try https://mydomain/myapp, It is not showing to myapp views.

Comment: Thankyou Anjaneyulu, I am new in Django framework, I don't know, How to checkout the URL configuration. Can you please help me.